# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '571,2'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I wrote this code: `df['Liquid Milk'] = df['Liquid Milk'].replace("", np.nan).astype('float64')`

I got an error below, not sure where is an error, have tried many different way, but still same error. Any help, appreciated.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-607dcacd5a1a> in <module>
----> 1 m['Liquid Milk(Mil Litres)']=m['Liquid Milk(Mil Litres)'].replace("", np.nan).astype('float64')
      2 
      3 
      4 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, **kwargs)
   5679             # else, only a single dtype is given
   5680             new_data = self._data.astype(dtype=dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors,
-> 5681                                          **kwargs)
   5682             return self._constructor(new_data).__finalize__(self)
   5683 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in astype(self, dtype, **kwargs)
    529 
    530     def astype(self, dtype, **kwargs):
--> 531         return self.apply('astype', dtype=dtype, **kwargs)
    532 
    533     def convert(self, **kwargs):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py in apply(self, f, axes, filter, do_integrity_check, consolidate, **kwargs)
    393                                             copy=align_copy)
    394 
--> 395             applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)
    396             result_blocks = _extend_blocks(applied, result_blocks)
    397 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    532     def astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None, **kwargs):
    533         return self._astype(dtype, copy=copy, errors=errors, values=values,
--> 534                             **kwargs)
    535 
    536     def _astype(self, dtype, copy=False, errors='raise', values=None,

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/blocks.py in _astype(self, dtype, copy, errors, values, **kwargs)
    631 
    632                     # _astype_nansafe works fine with 1-d only
--> 633                     values = astype_nansafe(values.ravel(), dtype, copy=True)
    634 
    635                 # TODO(extension)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/cast.py in astype_nansafe(arr, dtype, copy, skipna)
    700     if copy or is_object_dtype(arr) or is_object_dtype(dtype):
    701         # Explicit copy, or required since NumPy can't view from / to object.
--> 702         return arr.astype(dtype, copy=True)
    703 
    704     return arr.view(dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '571,2'
```

Comment: It looks like `571,2` has a comma as the decimal separator and the number parser is assuming it should be a period `.`. Maybe there is a way to tell the number parser to accept it, via locale settings?

Comment: A web search finds `read_csv` in pandas which has a `decimal` option you can set to comma; see: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Answer (score 0):

A float number's integer and fraction part must be separated by a `.` not a `,`. Replace all `,`s with `.`s.

```
float("571.2")
```

would work

```
float("571,2")
```

would fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked